# trying to get unique values

Tags: php

I've got the following code

```
foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $key => $reportRecord){
    $input = array($reportRecord->getField('Term').' - '.$reportRecord->getField('Year'));
    $result = array_unique($input);
    print_r($result);
}
```

which is producing output like

```
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Winter - 2010 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Spring - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
Array ( [0] => Summer - 2011 )
```

What I would like to do, is just get the unique values, in this case Winter - 2010, Spring 2011, Summer 2011.

Could someone advise me how to do this, I thought `array_unique` might be the solution, but I guess its the way the way the values are stored in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add the values to an array that's defined outside the scope of the loop?

```
$array = array();

foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $key => $reportRecord){
    $array[] = $reportRecord->getField('Term').' - '.$reportRecord->getField('Year');
}

$array = array_unique($array);
```

Comment: Make sure you add the second parameter `SORT_REGULAR`, otherwise all arrays will be cast to the tring `"Array"` and therefore be considered duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `$input` to a one item array with each loop.  Doing an `array_unique` on a one item array is going to return the same array you started with.

You need to build an array in the loop and then do the `array_unique` outside the loop. Something like this:

```
$input = array()
foreach($reportsResult->getRecords() as $key=>$reportRecord){
    $input[] = $reportRecord->getField('Term').' - '.$reportRecord->getField('Year');
}
$result = array_unique($input);
```